# How can I compute inverse matrix using cofactor?

Tags: determinant, inverse

> if $A^{-1}=(b_{ij})$, compute $b_{23}$ using cofactor.
>
> $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\ 0&0&4\\ 5&0&1 \end{pmatrix} $$

I know matrix of cofactors can be obtained by transpose of matrix $A$ and computing cofactors.

But, how can I compute determinant of $A$ which is $3\times 3$ matrix? or Is there are other solutions that not to use determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But the determinant is easy to compute:   $\left |\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\0&0&4\\5&0&1\end{matrix}\right|=-4\cdot \left|\begin{matrix}1&2\\5&0\end{matrix}\right |=-4\cdot-10=40$.

(This was done by *Laplace expansion*, or expansion by minors,  along the second row:  you actually get $$-0\cdot A_{21}+0\cdot A_{22}-4\cdot A_{23}$$.)

Comment: I mean how can I compute determinant of $A$, not $A_{23}$

Comment: That's what I computed.  You can go along the middle row...  (it's just a coincidence that it involves $A_{23}$)

Comment: Then, how can I compute inverse of $A_{23}$

Comment: Well, you want $b_{23}$, right?  I believe you need the transpose of the matrix of cofactors.   The cofactor $A_{32}=-4$.  So I'm getting $-\frac1{10}$. Check me on this...

Comment: Umm... how did you compute determinant? Is there a formula to compute? It seems like you used cofactor in your answer.

Comment: I did.  It's called expansion by minors.  The first two ($A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$) get multiplied by zero.

Comment: You used cofactor and multiplied by 4, how did you get 4?

Comment: Thank you Chris